# mysql ignore startement execution stopping on warning

Tags: mysql

I am using this sql query in my table to load data from a csv file:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/Users/Mayank/Desktop/8Jun/Furniture.csv' IGNORE INTO TABLE snap_furniture1
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' 
(@col1,@col2,@col5,@col6,@col13,@col14) 
set id=@col1,
title=@col2,
link=@col5,
image_link=@col6,
availibility=@col13,
effective_price=@col14;
```

However, when I execute it, I get a warning for a duplicate entry and the mysql execution stops there. I am using ignore, so the execution should not stop at warning. How do I make the execution to continue on warning/error